# Strip (get rid of) %0A (URL-encoding of a newline)

Tags: python, url, strip

## Strip url

I want to strip url from a newline (%OA). On a "normal" string you can use .rstrip() or strip() method, but for url it for some reason doesn't work.

```
string = "Hi, Steve\n"
print(string.rstrip()) # Hi, Steve

url = "https://python.iamroot.eu/genindex.html%0A"
print(url)           # "https://python.iamroot.eu/genindex.html%0A"
print(url.rstrip())   # "https://python.iamroot.eu/genindex.html%0A"
# I want to get: "https://python.iamroot.eu/genindex.html"
```

Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: `url.rstrip("%0A")`

Answer (score 1):

you can place characters in that you want removed.

> str.rstrip([chars])
>
> Return a copy of the string with trailing
> characters removed. The chars argument is a string specifying the set
> of characters to be removed. If omitted or None, the chars argument
> defaults to removing whitespace. The chars argument is not a suffix;
> rather, all combinations of its values are stripped.

See rstrip: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip

```
string = "Hi, Steve\n"
print(string.rstrip()) # Hi, Steve

url = "https://python.iamroot.eu/genindex.html%0A"
print(url)           # "https://python.iamroot.eu/genindex.html%0A"
print(url.rstrip())   # "https://python.iamroot.eu/genindex.html%0A"
print(url.rstrip('%0A'))
# I want to get: "https://python.iamroot.eu/genindex.html"
```

Comment: I can't belive I didn't come up with this myself, thank you

Comment: glad i could help @panSteven4 best of luck in your coding journey!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
url.rstrip('%0A')
```